# Capybara set host and port using non-rails application

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, bdd

I am using Capybara with a non-rails custom rack application. 
accordingly with official doc I have set:

```
Capybara.app = MyRackApp
```

I have a test that visit a login page. If I print:

```
p current_url
```

while running my test I see:

```
"http://www.example.com/login"
```

So, the question is: using a rack application Capybara does set automatically the host and the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no host and port set when using the default rack_test driver because it doesn't fire up a server thread to run the app, it directly communicates with the rack app.  If you use the selenium driver (or capybara-webkit, poltergeist, etc) then a port would be set and a server thread would be started.